# Linebreak IRC protocol

Tags: java, irc, bots

I've written an IRC bot in java, but I am having the following problem : I have a help function that returns all the functions of bots (usage, example,...) to a user in private message.

The problem is that if I send this line by line, messages get queued, and it can take up to 10 seconds to send one help request.

Now I solved this by putting all the help functions in one message, but everything of course is put on 1 line. This is negative for readability.

Is there a way to format messages using the irc protocol and especially is there a character for linebreak ? (/n from java does not work)

And if there is no such option, what would the best way be to make it more readable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. From the IRC [RFC 1459](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt):

> **IRC messages are always lines of characters terminated with a CR-LF**
>   **(Carriage Return - Line Feed) pair**, and these messages shall not
>   exceed 512 characters in length, counting all characters including
>   the trailing CR-LF.

I have never seen a message in IRC with a linebreak in it.

Comment: I would try to add a small delay between messages, so that you don't trigger a server-side slow down.